# 9 years old starting at an international school but doesn't speak English

Tags: education, bilingual, middle-childhood

We are moving to Lavia soon and our 9 year old son will be going to an International School, but he doesn't speak English at all. He already speaks two languages (Italian and Portuguese). Do you think it is too late for him to start school? He'll be starting in 5th grade and I'm freaking out!

Comment: I would contact the school and ask what to do. They probably encounter this frequently, and might have a summer school, or English learners classes or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The school should have a English as Second Language (ESL) type classes. You should contact them for more information.

From my personal experience, I started school in the United States at the age of 7 and didn't speak any English. While I did take ESL, the class wasn't as useful compared to full immersion in the new language. Now I speak English better than my mother tongue.